# Fourier distribution $\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I need help to calculate Fourier transform in distribution sense of $\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}$ in $D'(\mathbb{R}^3)$
we have $ \frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3)$

edit, Let $E(x)=\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}$, i have $\langle\hat E,\phi\rangle=\langle E,\hat \phi\rangle=\int_{R^3}\int_{R^3}\frac{e^{i|\xi|}}{|\xi|}e^{-i\xi.x}\phi(x)dx\,d\xi$

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. If you are new you are encouraged to learn math typesetting ( it seems you already know ). Also if something looks like it could be a homework question it can sometimes be easier to get answer if one shows any own attempts at solving a problem.

Comment: any help please?

Comment: is $R^3$ supposed to be $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes of course .

Comment: Maybe I can help you get some more tags. Having good tags can help people find the question.